# Create tunnel from Host to Gateway

Tags: vpn, gateway

I have configured a network map in Virtual Box. I have one VM that acts as a host on a network. I want this host to access a private network that is located behind a gateway, through a tunnel. The private network prefix is 10.0.20.0/24 and it is connected to a gateway 10.0.20.1. The gateway is connected to another network through another interface 192.168.20.5. The VPN server will be installed on the gateway. I have created a tunnel and assigned it an IP address on the gateway, then I did the same on the host thus connecting to the server.

I get that the client is connected to the server and the server to the client.

The problem is that I can not ping from the outside host to the private network.

I think the problem is my routing table. On the external host, I set default gateway as the tunnel interface. And on the gateway, I add the net where the provate network is and set the gateway as 10.0.20.1

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2):

On the gateway:

```
sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING --destination 10.0.20.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

On the host (presumably in 192.168.20.0/xx), from which you are trying to ping *10.0.20.0/24*:

```
ip route add 10.0.20.0/24 via 192.168.20.5
```